# espresso: log to test window not logcat

Tags: android, android-espresso

I would like to print some info in to the console window of the running test, NOT the log cat. I would like to be able to click on a running test and see the output for only that test.
[The console I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL1vR.png)

Comment: forgot to add the title to the image. The image is of the console window im talking about.

Comment: This window doesn't seem to exist anymore for instrumentation tests in Android Studio Dolphin (2021.3.1). It does for unit tests where it is the JVMs output and you can log via *println("soomething")*